# How to save data from input fields in Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, formik

I have a bunch of input fields in the formik form, which are displayed in a drawer. When the user enters something in the fields and sumbits the form, it adds queries and values to the url and sends a new request to load proper values to the datagrid component.
The problem is that when the user enters something in one of the input fields, closes the drawer and reopens it, the data is lost, same goes for when the form is applied - the datagrid values are corrrect, but when the user wants to modify previous filters, he needs to reenter everything, because the input fields are empty.
The data is saved into the url string and the request, but if I get it from there and put it into the input value, I cannot change it anymore cause `params.get()` value is set

the component looks something like `this.setFilters` function changes the url with `history.push()`

```
export const AccountFilters = ({ setFilters }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const params2 = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const name = params2.get("accountHolder");

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.drawerContent}>
        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
          Filters
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <Formik initialValues={formikInitialValues} onSubmit={setFilters}>
        {({
          values,
          handleChange,
          handleSubmit,
          handleReset,
          setFieldValue
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Box className={classes.fieldWrapper}>
              <TextField
                name={"accountHolder"}
                id={"accountHolder"}
                label="Account Holder Name"
                value={values.accountHolder}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Box>
            <Box className={classes.selects}>
              <Autocomplete
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label={"Select Account status"}
                    variant={"outlined"}
                  />
                )}
                options={accountStatusMenu}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                name={"status"}
                id={"status"}
                multiple
                value={values.status}
                onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue("status", value)}
              >
                ))}
              </Autocomplete>

              <Box className={"created"}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                  <KeyboardDatePicker
                    name={"timestampCreatedStart"}
                    id={"timestampCreatedStart"}
                    margin="normal"
                    label="Select CREATED start date"
                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    value={values.timestampCreatedStart}
                    onChange={(value) =>
                      setFieldValue("timestampCreatedStart", value)
                    }
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                      "aria-label": "change date"
                    }}
                  />
                  <KeyboardDatePicker
                    name={"timestampCreatedEnd"}
                    id={"timestampCreatedEnd"}
                    margin="normal"
                    label="Select CREATED end date"
                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    value={values.timestampCreatedEnd}
                    onChange={(value) =>
                      setFieldValue("timestampCreatedEnd", value)
                    }
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                      "aria-label": "change date"
                    }}
                  />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box style={{ display: "flex", gap: "10px" }}>
              <Button type={"submit"} variant="contained" color="primary">
                Apply filters
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={handleReset}
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
              >
                Reset filters
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Send full code
2. Please add break to your text

I thinks you don't need to use formik here. I saw you use Material-UI so state management is ok for this.

Formik is used to make forme with error handling to post like a new user or other complicated thing.

Just use `useState` or `useRef` and you'll be fine.